# I changed font of wordpress dashboard but it is slow!

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, dashboard, fonts

my language is Persian and I wanted to change font of wordpress dashboard To be more pleasant. so I created a plugin that works easy. just changes the font of HTML elements of dashboard by CSS (font-family).

But the problem is, while using the plugin, dashboard will be slow and every page takes longer to load. so I need your help to do it Without affecting the speed of the dashboard. How can do that?

you can download my plugin:
[REMOVED]

thanks a lot :)

Comment: Can you add the relevant code parts of your plugin to the question instead of making it available for donwload?

Comment: There's nothing in PHP or JS that would cause this, the likely cause is that you just have heavy font files and a slow computer, you would need to profile the page using the browser dev tools, but the cause and solution of this are frontend development issues, WordPress expertise will not be of help to you in solving this

Comment: Also, don't send people to a suspicious 3rd party website to get the code to debug, directly include it in your question

Comment: @TomJNowell thanks to you. you were right and the problem was solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @TomJNowell told me in the comment, it was because of heavy font files. so I decided to use just `woff2` format and removed other formats.